# Table record count laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to display the number of records from the blogs table. I am doing something wrong in the controller. I wrote count() function. In the view I am trying to display {{ $blogs_count }} but is wrong: Undefined variable: blogs_count (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel7_crud\resources\views\blogs\index.blade.php)

BlogController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Blog;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function count()
   {
      $blogs_count = Blog::count();
       return view('blogs', compact('blogs_count'));

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $blogs = Blog::latest()->paginate(50);

        return view('blogs.index',compact('blogs'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('blogs.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
          
        ]);

        Blog::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('blogs.index')
            ->with('success','Blog created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Blog $blog)
    {
        return view('blogs.show',compact('blog'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Blog $blog)
    {
        return view('blogs.edit',compact('blog'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Blog $blog)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
          
        ]);

        $blog->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('blogs.index')
            ->with('success','Blog updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Blog $blog)
    {
        $blog->delete();

        return redirect()->route('blogs.index')
            ->with('success','......');
    }
}
```

index.blade

```
@extends('blogs.layout')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Blogs</h2>
                **{{ $blogs_count }}**

            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('blogs.create') }}"> Add</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>L.p</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>surname</th>
         
            <th width="250px">Akcje</th>
        </tr>
       @foreach ($blogs as $blog)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $blog->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $blog->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $blog->surname }}</td>
          
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('blogs.destroy',$blog->id) }}" method="POST">

                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('blogs.show',$blog->id) }}">Show</a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('blogs.edit',$blog->id) }}">Edit</a>

                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

                </form>
            </td>

        @endforeach
    </table>

    {!! $blogs->links() !!}

@endsection
```

Comment: You're never passing `$blogs_count` to `blogs.index`... You're passing it to `blogs` in the `public function count()`, but that's the wrong file...

Comment: if you need the total of records of pagination, you can use $blogs->total() in the view

Comment: Thank you  @GiacomoM This solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the total count of rows of any Eloquent model simply use:

in blade view:

```
{{ $modelName->total() }}
```

in any php class:

```
$modelName->total();
```

or

```
ModelName::count();
```

Comment: I have one more issue. How to display the number of records from the blogs table on the welcome.blade.php home page. If I paste the code {$blogs->total()}} in the view it is an error: Undefined variable: blogs (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel7_crud\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: You need to pass that variable from controller to view for example in controller `return view('blade.view')->with('blogsTotal', Blog::count());` and in view just print it out `{{ $blogsTotal }}`

Comment: I tried:  public function count()
    {
       $blogsTotal = Blog::count();
        return view('blade.view')->with('blogsTotal', Blog::count());
        
      
       
    } But id doesn't work

Comment: what do you get when you do `dd(Blog::count());` before return view()...

Comment: Undefined variable: blogsTotal (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel7_crud\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: make this as a first line in your controller: `dd(Blog::count());`

Comment: I added the answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224780/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-kris).